# Multi-level Accordion Menu: Its possible to open each level with an anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Multi-Level Accordion Menu - from a FAQ - with 2 levels.

Each level have a 13 Questions / Answers.

My problem:

- One of the Questions/Answers have a lot of information. (almost 10 pages).
- The other Questions/Answers have 3, 4 lines of information each.
- The Question with many information is number 7.

Then When I click on question 7 - the answer 7 is open. with many information, and the user must scroll down the page to read all.

Until here, OK. no problem.

but at end - If I click on Question 8 - to read the answer, the menu closes question 7 (ok) - open question 8 (ok) - but the page still in the footer - the page dont scrolls up with the faq..

With all other questions - because they are small - I can see in same screen almost all 13 questions + the answer opened.

With question 7 - no. the page scrolls down and don't scrolls up - when we close the question 7.

There is a way to solve this? I think I need to create an anchor for each question..

Tks a lot!

https://jsfiddle.net/27sdLvmh/

- Please, click on Question 7, scrool down to read the answer and then click on question 8. the menu scrolls up - but the screen no.. and the user was lost in the footer of the page.. :D

JS:

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    var pluginName = 'accordion',
        defaults = {
            transitionSpeed: 300,
            transitionEasing: 'ease',
            controlElement: '[data-control]',
            contentElement: '[data-content]',
            groupElement: '[data-accordion-group]',
            singleOpen: true
        };

    function Accordion(element, options) {
        this.element = element;
        this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;
        this.init();
    }

    Accordion.prototype.init = function () {
        var self = this,
            opts = self.options;

        var $accordion = $(self.element),
            $controls = $accordion.find('> ' + opts.controlElement),
            $content =  $accordion.find('> ' + opts.contentElement);

        var accordionParentsQty = $accordion.parents('[data-accordion]').length,
            accordionHasParent = accordionParentsQty > 0;

        var closedCSS = { 'max-height': 0, 'overflow': 'hidden' };

        var CSStransitions = supportsTransitions();

        function debounce(func, threshold, execAsap) {
            var timeout;

            return function debounced() {
                var obj = this,
                    args = arguments;

                function delayed() {
                    if (!execAsap) func.apply(obj, args);
                    timeout = null;
                };

                if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
                else if (execAsap) func.apply(obj, args);

                timeout = setTimeout(delayed, threshold || 100);
            };
        }

        function supportsTransitions() {
            var b = document.body || document.documentElement,
                s = b.style,
                p = 'transition';

            if (typeof s[p] == 'string') {
                return true;
            }

            var v = ['Moz', 'webkit', 'Webkit', 'Khtml', 'O', 'ms'];

            p = 'Transition';

            for (var i=0; i<v.length; i++) {
                if (typeof s[v[i] + p] == 'string') {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        function requestAnimFrame(cb) {
            if(window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame) {
                return  requestAnimationFrame(cb) ||
                        webkitRequestAnimationFrame(cb) ||
                        mozRequestAnimationFrame(cb);
            } else {
                return setTimeout(cb, 1000 / 60);
            }
        }

        function toggleTransition($el, remove) {
            if(!remove) {
                $content.css({
                    '-webkit-transition': 'max-height ' + opts.transitionSpeed + 'ms ' + opts.transitionEasing,
                    'transition': 'max-height ' + opts.transitionSpeed + 'ms ' + opts.transitionEasing
                });
            } else {
                $content.css({
                    '-webkit-transition': '',
                    'transition': ''
                });
            }
        }

        function calculateHeight($el) {
            var height = 0;

            $el.children().each(function() {
                height = height + $(this).outerHeight(true);
            });

            $el.data('oHeight', height);
        }

        function updateParentHeight($parentAccordion, $currentAccordion, qty, operation) {
            var $content = $parentAccordion.filter('.open').find('> [data-content]'),
                $childs = $content.find('[data-accordion].open > [data-content]'),
                $matched;

            if(!opts.singleOpen) {
                $childs = $childs.not($currentAccordion.siblings('[data-accordion].open').find('> [data-content]'));
            }

            $matched = $content.add($childs);

            if($parentAccordion.hasClass('open')) {
                $matched.each(function() {
                    var currentHeight = $(this).data('oHeight');

                    switch (operation) {
                        case '+':
                            $(this).data('oHeight', currentHeight + qty);
                            break;
                        case '-':
                            $(this).data('oHeight', currentHeight - qty);
                            break;
                        default:
                            throw 'updateParentHeight method needs an operation';
                    }

                    $(this).css('max-height', $(this).data('oHeight'));
                });
            }
        }

        function refreshHeight($accordion) {
            if($accordion.hasClass('open')) {
                var $content = $accordion.find('> [data-content]'),
                    $childs = $content.find('[data-accordion].open > [data-content]'),
                    $matched = $content.add($childs);

                calculateHeight($matched);

                $matched.css('max-height', $matched.data('oHeight'));
            }
        }

        function closeAccordion($accordion, $content) {
            $accordion.trigger('accordion.close');

            if(CSStransitions) {
                if(accordionHasParent) {
                    var $parentAccordions = $accordion.parents('[data-accordion]');

                    updateParentHeight($parentAccordions, $accordion, $content.data('oHeight'), '-');
                }

                $content.css(closedCSS);

                $accordion.removeClass('open');
            } else {
                $content.css('max-height', $content.data('oHeight'));

                $content.animate(closedCSS, opts.transitionSpeed);

                $accordion.removeClass('open');
            }
        }

        function openAccordion($accordion, $content) {
            $accordion.trigger('accordion.open');
            if(CSStransitions) {
                toggleTransition($content);

                if(accordionHasParent) {
                    var $parentAccordions = $accordion.parents('[data-accordion]');

                    updateParentHeight($parentAccordions, $accordion, $content.data('oHeight'), '+');
                }

                requestAnimFrame(function() {
                    $content.css('max-height', $content.data('oHeight'));
                });

                $accordion.addClass('open');
            } else {
                $content.animate({
                    'max-height': $content.data('oHeight')
                }, opts.transitionSpeed, function() {
                    $content.css({'max-height': 'none'});
                });

                $accordion.addClass('open');
            }
        }

        function closeSiblingAccordions($accordion) {
            var $accordionGroup = $accordion.closest(opts.groupElement);

            var $siblings = $accordion.siblings('[data-accordion]').filter('.open'),
                $siblingsChildren = $siblings.find('[data-accordion]').filter('.open');

            var $otherAccordions = $siblings.add($siblingsChildren);

            $otherAccordions.each(function() {
                var $accordion = $(this),
                    $content = $accordion.find(opts.contentElement);

                closeAccordion($accordion, $content);
            });

            $otherAccordions.removeClass('open');
        }

        function toggleAccordion() {
            var isAccordionGroup = (opts.singleOpen) ? $accordion.parents(opts.groupElement).length > 0 : false;

            calculateHeight($content);

            if(isAccordionGroup) {
                closeSiblingAccordions($accordion);
            }

            if($accordion.hasClass('open')) {
                closeAccordion($accordion, $content);
            } else {
                openAccordion($accordion, $content);
            }
        }

        function addEventListeners() {
            $controls.on('click', toggleAccordion);

            $controls.on('accordion.toggle', function() {
                if(opts.singleOpen && $controls.length > 1) {
                    return false;
                }

                toggleAccordion();
            });

            $(window).on('resize', debounce(function() {
                refreshHeight($accordion);
            }));
        }

        function setup() {
            $content.each(function() {
                var $curr = $(this);

                if($curr.css('max-height') != 0) {
                    if(!$curr.closest('[data-accordion]').hasClass('open')) {
                        $curr.css({ 'max-height': 0, 'overflow': 'hidden' });
                    } else {
                        toggleTransition($curr);
                        calculateHeight($curr);

                        $curr.css('max-height', $curr.data('oHeight'));
                    }
                }
            });


            if(!$accordion.attr('data-accordion')) {
                $accordion.attr('data-accordion', '');
                $accordion.find(opts.controlElement).attr('data-control', '');
                $accordion.find(opts.contentElement).attr('data-content', '');
            }
        }

        setup();
        addEventListeners();
    };

    $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName,
                new Accordion( this, options ));
            }
        });
    }

})( jQuery, window, document );
```

Comment: To answer your Question, YES there is a way to solve this. Please provide the relevant code to replicate your problem. `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. `

Comment: provide us with a jsfiddle ,otherwise try to use this :
$('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("elementToScrollTo").offset().top
    }, "slow");

Comment: Hi @Mihai-T and Diptox - first of all, tks for your time! I'm creating the jsdfiddle right now!

Comment: Hi - just create the jsdfiddle! - If you click on QUESTION 7 (the biggest answers), scrool down to read the answer and click on Question 8 - the problem occurs.. thks a lot! - https://jsfiddle.net/27sdLvmh/

Comment: @Diptox I Try your sugestion too ($html, body..) - but with this line in script the accordion menu is frozen.. If I click on the first level nothing happens.. but all scroll of the page is ok (I have a left scroll menu and still working).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/27sdLvmh/1/)

changes line 191 -> 194

```
setTimeout(function()
{
   $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $content.prev().offset().top }, "fast");
},(1000/60)+200);
```

Comment: hi @diptox! tks a loooot!! For a better solution = I check the demo and the scroll up works fine if we dont scroll down to read question 7 - if we scroll down - the scroll returns in the middle of the answer.... - its easy to correct this? It's not a big problem to me.. but makes the solution better.. tks a lot. I will test now this into my site. feedback back you soon!

Comment: hi @Diptox! great! you save my life!! :DDDD ... works fine here. As I said, If we scroll down the script dont work as usual - the script returns to top but not to the current question.. and sometimes cut the answer. To solve this I put a +200 (or +100) after the top - like:  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $content.prev().offset().top+200 }, "fast");
},(1000/60)+200); - this create a "top-margin" - and make the scroll up more security for this little issue, to always return the current question and all the answer.

Comment: checked as answered! thks a lot.